# How to bypass Firebase auto-add Id when importing JSON

Tags: firebase

I have a json file:

```
{
"events": [
    {
        "title": "Wydarzenie 1",
        "start": "2015-03-19"
    },
    {
        "title": "Wydarzenie 2",
        "start": "2015-03-20"
    },
    {
        "title": "Wydarzenie 3",
        "start": "2015-03-21"
    }
]
```

}

But when I import the file to firebase it gets changed to:

```
{
"events": [
    "0": {
        "title": "Wydarzenie 1",
        "start": "2015-03-19"
    },
    "1": {
        "title": "Wydarzenie 2",
        "start": "2015-03-20"
    },
    "2": {
        "title": "Wydarzenie 3",
        "start": "2015-03-21"
    }
    ]
}
```

I want to have it in the same format as imported or at least retreive the data in imported format (no auto-id's e.g. 0, 1, 2). I need it to pass it as an argument to FullCallendar $scope.eventSources =[]. Could you tell me how to do that please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is simply how Firebase internally stores arrays: it stores them as associative arrays with numeric keys.

But when Firebase reads the data back into JavaScript, its `val()` method translates the data back into a normal array.

This behavior is explained in the section of the [Firebase documentation that describes array](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase).

If you're using AngularFire, it will even go to great lengths to map it into an [array that plays nicely with AngularJS's two-way data binding](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html).

If you want full control over the data format that Firebase stores, consider not passing your data as JSON. For example: if you'd provide the entire data structure as a string literal, Firebase would store that unmodified. But I wouldn't bother, because as said: Firebase's client-access libraries map your data back into the structure you're looking for.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much for this helpful answer. That's the reason I love angular + firebase. Pure and simple. Thanks